# Send email when entity field value is changed

Tags: rules

I have used [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module for notification when node is created, edited or deleted.

My site is in three languages and I use [Entity Translation](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_translation) for translating node's field.

Now I want notification when node's or entity field is changed/updated. Can I achieve it with [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use Rules to achieve this.

Here's how:

1. Create new rule that will react on "After updating existing content" event.
2. Use the following conditions: data comparison: `node:field-your-field` and `node-unchanged:field-your-field` and select "Negate: FALSE"
3. Create whichever actions you want, e.g. send mail, show message, etc.

Comment: NOT Data comparison
Parameter: Data to compare: [node:body], Data value: [node-unchanged:body] If i am not changing the body value, still i get email..But i need when it is changed..can we achieve that ?

Comment: Can i get "Label" value ? For example [node:title] is token and Title is Label value. So i need Label value. can i get it ?

Comment: Is the first data comparison equal to true?  So together they would look like this? [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/qHn5Apt.png)